# SQL solution not accepted in LeetCode

Tags: mysql, database

I wrote the following solution to a LeetCode problem:

```
SELECT ROUND(1.0*sum(t1.accepted_requests)/sum(t2.total_requests), 2) AS accept_rate
FROM (SELECT 'cool' AS common, ra.accepter_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ra.requester_id) AS accepted_requests
FROM request_accepted ra 
GROUP BY 1, 2) AS t1
JOIN
(SELECT 'cool' AS common, fr.send_to_id, COUNT(DISTINCT fr.sender_id) AS total_requests
FROM friend_request fr
GROUP BY 1, 2) AS t2
ON t1.common = t2.common
```

I ran the query and the output was identical to the expected answer posted by LeetCode. However, LeetCode's algorithm said my query is wrong and I couldn't figure out why.

The LeetCode problem is described below:

> In social network like Facebook or Twitter, people send friend requests and accept others’ requests as well. Now given two tables as below:

[image]

> Write a query to find the overall acceptance rate of requests rounded to 2 decimals, which is the number of acceptance divide the number of requests.

[image]

```
Note:
```

> The accepted requests are not necessarily from the table friend_request. In this case, you just need to simply count the total accepted requests (no matter whether they are in the original requests), and divide it by the number of requests to get the acceptance rate.
>
> It is possible that a sender sends multiple requests to the same receiver, and a request could be accepted more than once. In this case, the ‘duplicated’ requests or acceptances are only counted once.
>
> If there is no requests at all, you should return 0.00 as the accept_rate.
>
> Explanation: There are 4 unique accepted requests, and there are 5 requests in total. So the rate is 0.80.

Answer (score 2):

> There are 4 unique accepted requests, and there are 5 requests in total. So the rate is 0.80.

I guess this query should do it :

```
SELECT
    ROUND(COALESCE(acc.cnt/NULLIF(req.cnt, 0), 0), 2)
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM friends_request) req,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT requester_id, accepter_id) cnt FROM request_accepted) acc
```

What the query does is simply use two subqueries to compute both parts of the division that is performed in the outer query :

- `req` computes the denominator, ie the total number of requests
- `acc`computes the numerator, ie the count of distinct accepted requests

I tested it in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=885cdb0cd4b0915666d5915d2d79c1ed) and it's correctly returning `0.80` for your test data.

Comment: Thanks, @GMB. I tried your query in LeetCode but unfortunately it wasn't accepted either. In the query I wrote I had 'COUNT(DISTINCT)' statements in both the 'friend_request' and 'request_accepted' table, which should remove any duplicate, and my query also returned the same answer, 0.8. So I am confused as to why LeetCode didn't accept my query.